# Infinite Carousel and draw a winner from the lottery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create an infinite carousel with jQuery, where I can draw a winner from it.

First I want to show every participant of this lottery and there shall be an animation to show the winner.

The winner is known before, I just want an animation for it.

For example the Winner is on position 5, so I want to show the 10 participants and after that pick number 5.

I created a jsfiddle to show my current stand. `https://jsfiddle.net/qto9fnsv/`

I want an animation like this: `http://cases.goaggro.com/`

If its possible I want to play a sound in the draw like in my example.

Comment: Remove unnecessary greets and TIAs

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/22-dynamic-slides.html)?
I think Swiper's dynamic slides is the way to go and there are lots of ways to animate the slide action also you can dynamicly tell the slider to slide to the position you want using "slideTo();"